# Listing extended tags in files with Tagliib

Tags: c#, tags, taglib-sharp

I am working with .flac audio files that use extended tags for a bit of magic. There is a tag called ReleaseGuid. I want to be able to list the contents or create the tag if it doesn't exist. I have done the prerequisite beating of my head against the wall for three days now. I have found a way to add a usertextinformation frame...although I don't see the value just the Owner. Please help me figure this out.

The following are lines of code that at least compile and seem to do something.
I need to get this to the point where I can add the needed tag.

```
File objFile = TagLib.File.Create(path);
  TagLib.Id3v2.Tag id3v2tag = (TagLib.Id3v2.Tag)objFile.GetTag TagLib.TagTypes.Id3v2, true);

if (id3v2tag != null)
        {
            // Get the private frame, create if necessary.
            PrivateFrame frame = PrivateFrame.Get(id3v2tag, "Mytag", true);


            frame.PrivateData = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes "MyInfo");
            id3v2tag.AddFrame(frame);
        }
```

I have used mp3tag to see the tags I am needing by clicking on "extended tags".
Which type of tags would these be if I can add them using mp3tag? How do I read/write them using taglib?

Comment: I assume you already SAVE your modifications back into the file with something like objFile.Save(); ?

Answer (score 0):

To search for the tag type, you can open the (.flac) audio file in a texteditor like Notepad++ and search for your 'ReleaseGuid'. In front of this ID you will see the type like TXXX or PRIV or COMM.

Or you can have a look into the documentation (source code?) of the program who writes this 'ReleaseGuid' in your audio files.

Comment: Yes, I save what I modify....the point is I can't locate the tags that I need to change or create if they aren't there. I can do this with a combination of code and mp3tag software....but that's not how I want to do it.

Comment: Here is a powershell solution:

Comment: This uses the same library, taglib-sharp, as what I'm trying to use in my code. The info in "Tags", the "03_You_Shook_Me...." part is what I'm looking for. It's very easy to get the normal tags associated with an mp3 or flac file....I just can't figure out where to find the Tags....can anybody help?

Comment: dir M:\Music\test | Foreach-Object { Get-MediaInfo $_.FullName}
Album              : 
AlbumArtists       : 
Artists            : 
StartTag           : TagLib.NonContainer.StartTag
Tags               : {03 You Shook Me [PHC] 1423f043527cec76ae181bd9fb9a3cab067facce916f6cc819de630da9903bbc [replaygain_track_gain] -5.36 dB [Tool Name] PonoMusic 
                     World [Tool Version] 20.0.36, TagLib.Id3v1.Tag}
Title              : 03 You Shook Me

Comment: OK...I've found the tags I'm looking for in the file....but there is no tag type in front of them. I can see the source for get-mediainfo....there are add-member statements to append addition tags to the object created by the tagfile.file.create statement. They add properties "tag" and "property". And I can isolate the Tags by using select-object Tags. I can then get just the line I want by using | find "PHC" then put it in a file...this is all a kluge work-around for what should be easy in c#.

Comment: And oh yeah....I don't have access to the source of the program that writes these tags.

Comment: So I've found another library....UltraID3....which I can figure out how to get the tag I'm looking for using it.....so my hint is that it is a idv23userdefinedtextframe...which appears to be called usertextinformationframe in taglib-sharp. I'm trying to figure out how to create a new frame in ultraid3lib...or use what clues I've found there to use taglib-sharp.